# Why does exporting an image change its width in Sketch?

Tags: sketch-app, dimensions

These icons have the very same width in Sketch:

[image]

When I export them as PNGs (3x size), the inbox icon has a width of 69px, while the trash's width is 63px.

[image]

Why is that? Why don't they have the same width when exported?

Comment: Could it be that the inbox icon has a stroke which changes the width for 6 px? for 1.5px on each side. I haven't used sketch at all

Comment: @Eli - thanks very much! This is the right answer. Please feel free to post your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it. Also, you could mention that in Sketch, to solve this, you have to "create slices" of the icons.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be that the inbox icon has a stroke which changes the width for 6 px? for 1.5px on each side. I haven't used sketch at all

**"Thanks! I would like to add: to fix this problem create slices in Sketch and then export them" - CeceXX**

Comment: Thanks! I would like to add: to fix this problem create slices in Sketch and then export them.